# Error with sqlite statement

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

i got a sqlite database but something is wrong with my statement this is my method to open the database and to retrieve some data i need:

```
    - (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    // First, test for existence.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"monsterDB.DB"];

    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
    {
        // TODO: auch aktuelle version ? -> server check
        return;
    }

    // TODO: The writable database does not exist, so copy the default from server to the appropriate location.
}

- (sqlite3 *)getDBConnection
{
    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"monsterDB.DB"];

    // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
    sqlite3 *newDBConnection;
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBConnection) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened :)");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database :(");
    }
    return newDBConnection;
}

- (DEMonster *)getEventByType:(NSString *)type
{
    DEMonster *result = nil;
    sqlite3 *connection = [self getDBConnection];
    NSString *textString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE type = '%@' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;", @"city"];                 // TODO: Hier type nehmen für testzwecke nur city
    const char *text = [textString UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *select_statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(connection, text, -1, &select_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // error
        NSLog(@"Error");
        sqlite3_close(connection);
        return result;
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(select_statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        result = [[DEMonster alloc] init];

        result.name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char const *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 1)];
        result.attacks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char const *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 2)], [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char const *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 3)], nil];
        result.defenses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char const *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 4)], [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char const *)sqlite3_column_text(select_statement, 5)], nil];
        int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(select_statement, 6);
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(select_statement, 6) length:length];
        result.monsterIcon = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        result.attackValue = sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 12);
        result.defenseValue = sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 13);
        result.attackValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 8)], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 9)], nil];
        result.defenseValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 10)], [NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(select_statement, 11)], nil];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(select_statement);

    sqlite3_close(connection);
    return (result);
}
```

Basically the problem is in the "getEventByType" method. Somehow i always get the "Error" NSLog, because my statement does not return "SQLITE_OK".

The output looks like this:

```
    2014-04-15 22:24:15.805 MonsterSafari[3701:60b] Database Successfully Opened :)
2014-04-15 22:24:15.806 MonsterSafari[3701:60b] Error
```

As you can see the database looks to be opened successfully, but somehow the statement looks to be wrong. When i run the exact same statement in my sqlbrowser (some app i use to browse the sqlite database) the query works just fine. Any idea what could possibly be wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what does sqlite3_errmsg return??

Comment: BTW - DO NOT use `stringWithFormat` to build a query. Bad things will happen. Do it properly by binding values to the query.

Comment: It says "no such table monsters" but its definetly there.

Comment: Somewhere, perhaps, but not there.

Comment: Hint:  Open a command window on your Mac, cd to the directory in the simulator working directory where your DB file should be, and start `sqlite3` on that file.  Then do `.tables`.  Is your table there?  (Almost certainly not.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Sqlite3 SQLITE\_ERROR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310893/ios-sqlite3-sqlite-error)

Comment: A common mistake is to have an error in the database creation logic (even if you had a problem in a previous version) and the `sqlite3_open` would create blank database. So (a) uninstall and reinstall app (to get rid of any blank database); (b) use `sqlite3_open_v2` which will not create blank database; and (c) double check your database creation routine.

Comment: Did you cd to the simulator file system (not the DB in your Xcode project or in the bundle)?

Comment: yes i did, but like i said the comment from @Rob made it work for me